# Display selected radio button value on the panel title

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to display the selected radio button value on a panel title.

This is my js file

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".child_option_radio").on("change", function(){
      elem = $(this);
      if ($(this).is(':checked'))
       {
         alert($(this).val());
       }

       $("#part_child_" + elem.attr("data-option-subid")).html(e);
       alert("#part_child_" + elem.attr("data-option-subid"));
  });
```

My part_child.erb file

```
<div class="row">
    <%= options_radio_tag part_child, class: "child_option_radio", "data-option-subid" => part_child.id, "data-option-name" => part_child.name %>
</div>
```

This is my helper file for option_radio_tag for part child

```
  def options_radio_tag(part_child)
   html = ""
  attr_name = "order[part][#{part_child.parent.id}][children][][part]  [#{part_child.id}][option][][id]"
  part_child.options.each do |o|
  html += "<div class='col-sm-2'>"
  html += label_tag "#{attr_name}", raw("<input id='order_part_#{part_child.id}_option_#{o.id}', data-option-subid='option_subid_#{o.id}', data-option-name='#{o.name}',  name='#{attr_name}' type='radio' value='#{o.id}' #{o.is_default? ? 'checked' : ''} data-option-subid='option_subid_#{o.id}'> #{o.name}")
  html += "</div>"
 end
html.html_safe
 end
```

Please let me know If you need any more details.

PS: With the above code I am getting this

> wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a variable `e` which is not present in the handler method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".child_option_radio").on("change", function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#part_child_" + elem.attr("data-option-subid")).html(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please check the updated question. Removed that silly mistake of variable e. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".child_option_radio").on("change", function(){
      elem = $("input[type=radio]:checked.child_option_radio");
      alert(elem.val()); // Will give you the value of selected radio button
      $("#part_child_" + elem.attr("data-option-subid")).html(elem.val());
      });
```

Comment: Yes, Alert doesn't come up

Comment: Check the updated code.. Their was a silly mistake in selector

Comment: Your `<input type="checkbox"... ` has class `.child_option_radio`, right?

Comment: Just to let you know the input type is radio button and not checkbox

Comment: And what  is the name of the radio button?

Comment: already tried this, doesn't work.. Let's not make it look ugly here in comment section, maybe you put another answer..

Comment: Hey @void can you check this question..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628309/display-selected-value-on-a-panel

Comment: Can you tell me what is the selector for this panel?